# Parsing Bing Search API results for Django Template

Tags: python, django

I have a simple view to fetch bing search results using their official API (no scraping :)
for example purposes I have hardcoded the query being Pfizer

```
def bing (request):
    url = "https://bing-web-search1.p.rapidapi.com/search"
    
    querystring = {"q":"pfizer","mkt":"en-us","textFormat":"Raw","safeSearch":"Off","freshness":"Day"}
    
    headers = {
        'x-bingapis-sdk': "true",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "bing-web-search1.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print (response.text)
    
    #return render (request, 'home.html', {'page':rows})
```

the print returns a very complex (for me :) JSON

```
{"_type": "SearchResponse", "queryContext": {"_type": "QueryContext", "originalQuery": "pfizer"}, "webPages": {"_type": "Web\/WebAnswer", "webSearchUrl": "https:\/\/www.bing.com\/search?q=pfizer", "totalEstimatedMatches": 220000, "value": [{"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0", "contractualRules": [{"_type": "ContractualRules\/LicenseAttribution", "targetPropertyName": "snippet", "targetPropertyIndex": 0, "mustBeCloseToContent": true, "license": {"_type": "License", "name": "CC-BY-SA", "url": "http:\/\/creativecommons.org\/licenses\/by-sa\/3.0\/"}, "licenseNotice": "Text under CC-BY-SA license"}], "name": "Pfizer - Wikipedia", "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Pfizer", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Pfizer", "snippet": "Pfizer Inc. (\/ ˈ f aɪ z ər \/) is an American multinational pharmaceutical corporation. One of the world's largest pharmaceutical companies, it is ranked 57 on the 2018 Fortune 500 list of the largest United States corporations by total revenue.. Headquartered in Manhattan, Pfizer develops and produces medicines and vaccines for a wide range of medical disciplines, including immunology ...", "deepLinks": [{"_type": "WebPage", "name": "Zoetis", "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Zoetis", "snippet": "Zoetis Inc. (\/zō-EH-tis\/) is the world's largest producer of medicine and vaccinations for pets and livestock. The company was a subsidiary of Pfizer, the world's largest drug maker, but with Pfizer's spinoff of its 83% interest in the firm it is now a completely independent company.The company directly markets the products in approximately 45 countries, and sells the products in more than ..."}, {"_type": "WebPage", "name": "Charles Pfizer", "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Charles_Pfizer", "snippet": "Karl Christian Friedrich Pfizer (March 22, 1824 – October 19, 1906), known as Charles Pfizer, was a German-American businessman and chemist who co-founded the Pfizer pharmaceutical company with his cousin, Charles F. Erhart, in 1849, as Chas. Pfizer & Co. Inc."}, {"_type": "WebPage", "name": "Albert Bourla", "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Albert_Bourla", "snippet": "Albert Bourla (Greek: Άλμπερτ Μπουρλά, born 21 October 1961) is a Greek business executive and veterinarian who serves as the chairman and chief executive officer of the American pharmaceutical corporation Pfizer.He joined the company in 1993 and has held several executive roles across Pfizer's divisions, including Zoetis (then known as Animal Health), the Vaccines, Oncology and ..."}], "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T23:16:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": true}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.1", "name": "FDA warns U.K. plan to delay 2nd doses of Pfizer vaccine ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.cbsnews.com\/news\/covid-vaccine-fda-united-kingdom-pfizer-dose-timing-significant-risk-public-health\/", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.cbsnews.com\/news\/covid-vaccine-fda-united-kingdom-pfizer-dose-timing...", "snippet": "Facing a surge in infections, U.K. officials said the 2nd dose of the Pfizer vaccine can wait up to 12 weeks. The FDA says that decision is \"not rooted solidly in the available evidence.\"", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T23:18:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.2", "name": "The UK is delaying second Pfizer\/BioNTech shot: Here's ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.cnbc.com\/2021\/01\/05\/the-uk-is-delaying-second-pfizer\/biontech-shot-heres-what-we-know.html", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.cnbc.com\/2021\/01\/05\/the-uk-is-delaying-second-pfizer\/biontech-shot-heres...", "snippet": "\"Pfizer and BioNTech's Phase 3 study for the COVID-19 vaccine was designed to evaluate the vaccine's safety and efficacy following a 2-dose schedule, separated by 21 days.", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T21:30:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.3", "name": "Valley Health starts to administer second dose of Pfizer ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.whsv.com\/2021\/01\/05\/valley-health-starts-to-administer-second-dose-of-pfizer-vaccine\/", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.whsv.com\/...\/valley-health-starts-to-administer-second-dose-of-pfizer-vaccine", "snippet": "A week after Valley Health received the first shipment of the Pfizer vaccine, the hospital system, which serves the Northern Shenandoah Valley, parts of West Virginia and Maryland, received its ...", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T23:38:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.4", "name": "Peruvian Minister Raises 'Controversy' Over Pfizer Vaccine ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.usnews.com\/news\/world\/articles\/2021-01-05\/peruvian-minister-raises-controversy-over-pfizer-vaccine-liability-clause", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.usnews.com\/news\/world\/articles\/2021-01-05\/peruvian-minister-raises...", "snippet": "A small shopping basket filled with vials labeled \"COVID-19 - Coronavirus Vaccine\" and a medical sryinge are placed on a Pfizer logo in this illustration taken November 29, 2020.", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T21:18:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.5", "name": "Thousands of doses of Pfizer's COVID-19 vaccine arrive in ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.orlandoweekly.com\/Blogs\/archives\/2021\/01\/05\/thousands-of-doses-of-pfizers-covid-19-vaccine-arrive-in-orange-county-on-tuesday", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.orlandoweekly.com\/Blogs\/archives\/2021\/01\/05\/thousands-of-doses-of-pfizers...", "snippet": "A total of 19,500 doses of the Pfizer vaccine were received by Orange County government this morning, and were immediately whisked into specialty freezers that Orange County had already purchased ...", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T21:56:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.6", "name": "WHO recommends 2 doses of Pfizer COVID-19 vaccine within ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.nasdaq.com\/articles\/who-recommends-2-doses-of-pfizer-covid-19-vaccine-within-21-28-days-2021-01-05", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.nasdaq.com\/articles\/who-recommends-2-doses-of-pfizer-covid-19-vaccine...", "snippet": "GENEVA, Jan 5 (Reuters) - COVID-19 patients should take two doses of the Pfizer PFE.N and BioNTech 22UAy.DE vaccine within a period of 21-28 days, the World Health Organization said on Tuesday as ...", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T18:21:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}, {"_type": "WebPage", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.7", "name": "WPAFB begins administering Pfizer COVID-19 vaccine to base ...", "url": "https:\/\/www.whio.com\/news\/local\/wpafb-begins-administering-pfizer-covid-19-vaccine-base-healthcare-workers\/I7R3YVKJTZHGDKKCAGTHXCED3Q\/", "isFamilyFriendly": true, "displayUrl": "https:\/\/www.whio.com\/news\/local\/wpafb-begins-administering-pfizer-covid-19-vaccine...", "snippet": "The Pfizer vaccine is currently being administered using two doses 21 days apart. “The COVID-19 vaccine is another item in our toolkit as medical professionals to help combat the pandemic, one ...", "dateLastCrawled": "2021-01-05T21:57:00.0000000Z", "language": "en", "isNavigational": false}]}, "rankingResponse": {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingResponse", "mainline": {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingGroup", "items": [{"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 0, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.0"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 1, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.1"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 2, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.2"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 3, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.3"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 4, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.4"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 5, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.5"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 6, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.6"}}, {"_type": "Ranking\/RankingItem", "answerType": "WebPages", "resultIndex": 7, "value": {"_type": "Identifiable", "id": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/#WebPages.7"}}]}}}
```

my question is how can I pass the results (name, url and snippet) in a suitable format for the django render ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your JSON, in the first step, you need to decode this JSON, and then pass data to the template, iterate over data and display it.

following is the code for the view

```
def test_view(request):
    url = "https://bing-web-search1.p.rapidapi.com/search"
    
    querystring = {"q":"pfizer","mkt":"en-us","textFormat":"Raw","safeSearch":"Off","freshness":"Day"}
    
    headers = {
        'x-bingapis-sdk': "true",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "bing-web-search1.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    json_decode = json.loads(response.text)
    return render(request,'index.html', {"result": json_decode['webPages']['value']})
```

and in the template, you can render data using the following code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>Snippet</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for res in result %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ res.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ res.url }}</td>
                <td>{{ res.snippet }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps and solves your problem.